# How to divide a n dimensional simplex in n+1 equal parts

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I want to divide a n dimensional simplex (convex hull of n+1 points) in n+1 parts. E.g. consider the simplex in 2-D which is the convex hull of points (0,0,1), (0,1,0) amd (1,0,0). It can be divided in three parts as
$P_1 = \{(0,1,0),(1/2,1/2,0),(0,1/2,1/2),(1/3,1/3,1/3)\}$

$P_2 = \{(1,0,0),(1/2,1/2,,0),(1/2,0,1/2),(1/3,1/3,1/3)\}$

$P_3 = \{(0,0,1),(1/2,0,1/2),(0,1/2,1/2),(1/3,1/3,1/3)\}$

I can somehow arrive at these partitions by considering intersection of some halfspaces (line joining the vertex to the midpoint of the other side). However, I am unable to extend this to higher dimensions.

Is  there an algorithm in literature which does the same partitions. Can someone point me to some reference.

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for "Voronoi cells" :-)

Comment: This is not a research level question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, there are much more such divisions. The group of simplex is $S_{n+1}$, so it contains a subgroup $H=\langle (123\dots n+1)\rangle$ of order $n+1$ acting transitively on the hyperfaces. Now take a ray $r$ from the center $O$ of the simplex, and let $\{r_1,\dots,r_{n+1}\}$ be its orbit under the action of $H$. Every $n$ of these rays generate a polyhedral cone, the union of these cones is the whole space (unless something degenerates), and $H$ permutes these cones transitively. Hence $H$ also permutes the intersections of these cones with the simplex, and they are congruent. So, we obtain a desired division.

The pictures below show two types of such divsion of a regular tetrahedron.

[image: two divisions of a tetrahedron]

Answer (score 5):

The magic word is "barycenter". The convex hull of the barycenter and any one face of the simplex has the right volume.

Comment: just look up *barycentric subdivision* please before you start second guessing the answer. It is what you want.